# Snippet with selected line inserts unwanted new line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

If I select a line with tripple click and then select a snippet like the default #region snippet

```
#region $name$
    $selected$ $end$
#endregion
```

then I end up with an unexpected extra line between my selected text and `#endregion`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the snippet with

```
#region $name$
$selected$#endregion $end$
```

takes care of the unexpected extra line and seems to work for both whole lines and other selected text.